# Discrete Mathematics Division Algorithm proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm not quite sure how to do this problem if anyone can do a step by step to help me understand it I would appreciate it a lot.

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers with $b > a$, and suppose that the division algorithm yields
> $b = a \cdot q + r$,
> with $0 \leq r < a$.  (note: its a zero)

Prove that
$$\mathrm{lcm}(a, b) − \mathrm{lcm}(a, r) = \frac{a^2 \cdot q}{\gcd(a, b)}.$$

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something.  I am confused by what you intend by the RHS: $\displaystyle a^2 \cdot q \mid \gcd(a, b)$.  Please explain what you want this expression to signify.

Comment: meaning a squared times q divded by gcd(a,b)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you learned any facts/theorems about gcd and lcm that might help? For example, I think $\text{lcm}(a,b) \cdot \gcd(a,b) = |a \cdot b|$ will come in handy here.

Comment: Also, gcd$(a,b)$ = gcd$(a,r)$.

Comment: lcm(a,b)=a times b divided by gcd(a,b) is one of the ones I learned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Euclidean algorithm for gcd: $$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}\gcd(a,b) \stackrel{\text{gcd symmetric}}= \gcd(b,a) \stackrel{\text{def. }b}{=} \gcd(a\cdot q+r,a) \stackrel{\text{Eucl.}}{=} \gcd(a,r).\tag{1}$$

Also, it is a fact that for any integers $x, y \geq 0$: $$\lcm(x,y) = \frac{xy}{\gcd(x,y)}.\tag{2}$$

Combining these facts, you get:

\begin{align*}
\lcm(a,b)-\lcm(a,r) ~&\stackrel{(2)}=~ \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)} - \frac{ar}{\gcd(a,r)} 
 ~\stackrel{(1)}=~  \frac{a\cdot(b-r)}{\gcd(a,b)}
~\stackrel{\text{def. }b}= ~\frac{a \cdot (a \cdot q)}{\gcd(a,b)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: howd you the last part where its a times (b-r)/gcd(a,b) how did that equal to a times (a timesq)/gcd(a,b)

Comment: @Xenon Remember that $b=aq+r$, so here I'm just doing $b-r = (aq+r)-r = aq$.